# How can i send a file to browser so that user can open/save?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, httpresponse, webclient

I have a button on click of it i have to call a asynchronous method which has to download the data from a shared path and prompt the user to save/open.

```
   **ButtonClick Method**
    Private Sub btnDownload_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.ServerClick
    Dim obj As New delAsyncMethodCaller(AddressOf downloadReport) As Byte()
    Dim iAr As IAsyncResult = obj.BeginInvoke(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AsyncComplete), Nothing)
    End Sub

    Public Function downloadReport() As Byte()
    Dim strFileName As String = "Test.txt"
    Dim FileName As String = "Test.txt"
    Dim strDestinationPath As String ="\\appsupld\Uploads\OfficeAutomation\APR\Downloads\"
    Dim myStringWebResource As String = Nothing
    Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
    myStringWebResource = strDestinationPath + strFileName
    Dim data As Byte() = myWebClient.DownloadData(myStringWebResource)
    return data

    End Function

    Public Sub AsyncComplete(iAr As IAsyncResult)
    Dim ar As AsyncResult = DirectCast(iAr, AsyncResult)
    Dim del As delAsyncMethodCaller = DirectCast(ar.AsyncDelegate, delAsyncMethodCaller)
    Dim result As Integer = del.EndInvoke(iAr)
End Sub
```

This piece of code is downloading the file into the path which i have specified automatically. How can get a prompt so that user can open/save it.

When a user clicks on download the operations should be done asynchronously so that user can work other things, once the async operation is complete he should be provided with a pop to open/save the document?

I can't use Response.binarywrite(), as the Response is nothing, as the download method ends after the asynchronous call

Comment: that code just saves the document to a fileshare. Not the same as downloading it to the user's machine. You can easily google sample code to do that if you prefer. However if it's your intent to save to this fileshare (presumably the user's machine can also access that path?) then you can just return any information you like to the browser to show them where to look for it. In some browsers a hyperlink to a UNC fileshare path will work, but not always.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Adyson. My intent is to downloading it in user's machine. I tried to send the data back from the method and though i have the data i am not able to download it in user's machine without using response properties.

Comment: You'll have to show what you tried, because it should be possible to return a file from a HTTP request - again there are lots of examples available online already which work correctly. I assume this is an ASP.NET application? Or are you in a Windows Forms environment?

Comment: It is an asp.net application. I have edited what i have tried.

Comment: I can't see any download code. You've just edited in your button event handler function's definition, that's all. Did you mean to add something else?

Comment: No, Inside button event handler i call the downloadBT method which is async and do the operations.

Comment: It seems fairly obvious that you won't be able to fetch the remote file async, if you then want to forward it on to the user. In fact it would be counter-productive to do so. If you want to return it in the response, you have to wait until it's ready before you can return the response. That's fairly simple logic - you can't return something you haven't yourself received yet. So start by not using async, and then research the headers etc you need to set in order to return the file to the user.